# Flynn's Taxonomy as a modern classification

Tags: computer-architecture

Flynn's Taxonomy was a classification of computer architectures published in 1966. Computing has changed a lot since then. Is this taxonomy still useful? What are some of its shortcomings for evaluating modern computing systems?